# A luigi task fails if the next file is already completed

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

I have a pipeline built with Luigi in which some taks require other tasks and each task creates a file.
Something like:

```
TaskA-------->TaskB---------> TaskC-------->TaskD
(fileA)      (fileB)         (fileC)       (fileD)
```

The first time I run the pipeline, everything runs well and gets created.

If I run the pipeline again, nothing gets run since TaskD was completed already.

If I manually delete fileB (made by TaskB), I expected it to be recreated and everything else running but the pipeline fails.

yes, fileB gets recreated but TaskC fails, with the error message saying that fileC already exist.

Is there a way for the subsequent files to be recreated again? Or fileC be overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is exactly how Luigi is set up to run. When you specify which tasks to run (in `luigi.build` or the cli), you are specifying which tasks need to be completed for Luigi to consider its job done. Luigi will not care about your pipeline unless you tell it to. One way to do this would be to inform Luigi of all tasks you do care about, which in this case seem to be TaskB and Task D. So, it would look something like:

```
luigi.build([TaskD(...), TaskB(...)])
```